# How can I edit the colors in an already-placed, custom gradient in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

Here's a basic list of what I did to the document before I sat down at the computer tonight:

- Customized a gradient
- Applied the gradient to the image in the usual way (mouse stroke), in its own layer
- Saved the file (as a .psd)

Now, it is sometime later. I'm opening it up on a different computer and what I'm trying to do is edit the way that gradient appears on the photo. I tried selecting the layer with the gradient in it and then selecting the gradient tool to attempt to edit it, but the gradient tool does not show me the *current* gradient (what with all my customizations), as I would have expected.

I'm trying to avoid re-creating this gradient again from scratch since all I really want to do is change the color and orientation slightly. It's not the most complicated of gradients, but starting over would lead to me spending an hour tweaking things to get them just right again. I've got other things to work so, in the meantime, I thought I'd see if any of you guys knew what to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Photoshop, the only way to retrieve gradient color data is to...

A) use a Shape/Vector layer which has a gradient fill.

B) Save a gradient in the Gradient Editor dialog window.

C) Apply the gradient as a Gradient Overlay Layer Style.

D) Use a gradient fill layer via `Layer > New Fill Layer > Gradient`

If you did none of these, then the specific gradient data is not stored anywhere directly. You can use the eyedropper tool to sample colors at the end of the gradient and rebuild it, but you can't directly access the gradient data.

Comment: That's... so not the answer I was hoping for. *sigh* I guess I'll know better next time.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to make editable gradients that can be edited or changed easily whenever and however u please, is to use > add layer style > Gradient overlay .

Then at any time, from the layer of the gradient: you can click on the effects icon (eye icon) > gradient ovelay icon and edit it as you may wish .(of course in the PSD file) .

Answer (score 1):

Scott had some great answers. A few other options are:

1. Apply a Hue/Saturation Adjustment Mask and play with the
   HSL values. (change existing)
2. Apply a color overlay effect and change the blend mode to
   screen. (change existing; best on black/white gradients)
3. Use a layer mask on a shape layer and apply the gradient
   to the layer mask. (new gradients; solid to transparent only)

Answer (score 0):

1. Take the layer of the gradient to a new image.
2. Add a new layer to the new image.
3. Bucket fill it with the colour you want for the gradient.
4. Set the new layer to color mode.

Now you have the old gradient with the new colour. "Copy visible" to your original image and you are ready. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the gradient layer is selected then go to image, adjustments and then hue and saturation, finally slide the hue to whatever color you want or use the eyedrop by moving the mouse off the adjusment page.

Comment: Can you please visualise what you mean with one or more screenshots? Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score -1):

For editing the colors of a Photo/Image. At first you have to Create a path on the image where you can edit. Then select the path and Change the colors. If you want to use gradient then select the path, take the gradient tools (Or press G) and use gradient color as your wish. At last, save the file as .psd format Or another format, what you want.